# Is there any way to handle exception if we pass empty spaces in path parameter of integer type in OpenApi(Swagger)?

Tags: swagger, spring-webflux, openapi, swagger-codegen, openapi-generator

I am trying implement below endpoint URL in swagger:

`users/{userId}/accounts/{accountId}`

I am using Spring Boot and OpenApi 3.0.1. The codegen generates the delegate interfaces from where we need to start service implementation.
I am facing issue when I am passing white spaces as accountId. Its throwing 500 Internal server error.

In console I can see error at org.springframework.web.reactive.result.method.annotation.PathVariableMethodArgumentResolver.handleMissingValue(PathVariableMethodArgumentResolver.java:95)

Is there any way in Open Api so that we can handle this case?

Thanks

Please find yaml endpoint below:

```
     delete:
       tags:
         - UserAccounts
       summary: Delete accounts for users
       description: Delete accounts for users
       operationId: DeleteUserAccounts
       parameters:
         - $ref: '#/components/parameters/uid'
         - $ref: '#/components/parameters/token'
         - $ref: '#/components/parameters/accountId'
         - $ref: '#/components/parameters/userId'
  responses:
         200:
```

AccountId parameter is defined as:

```
    accountId:
      name: accountId
      in: path
      description: "account Id"
      required: true
      schema:
        type: integer
        format: int64
        example: 34562712
```

Comment: Can you post the controller code with parameter annotations? Of if you generate the code from the OpenAPI definition, please post the full endpoint definition (YAML/JSON). How do you send the request with spaces - via curl, Swagger UI, a client app, etc.?

Comment: @Helen, I am using Postman to send the request. I have updated the endpoint definition above.